# FullCalender functionality not working after activating locker service

Tags: salesforce-lightning

FullCalender functionality is not working if we activate locker service.

I tried different versions of fullcalender 3.1.0 and jquery 2.2.4 but still fullcalender functionality not working and no error in the back end. I can see only blank screen.
PFB versions which I have used in my code.

```
| FullCalendar |---------| 3.1.0 |
| jQuery |-----| 2.2.2 and 2.2.4 |
| jQuery UI |-----------| 1.11.4 |

code

<ltng:require styles="/resource/FullCalender/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css,
                  /resource/SLDS0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" 
              scripts="/resource/jqueryJSmin2_2_4,
                   /resource/jqueryUIto/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js,
                   /resource/FullCalender/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js" 
                   afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this (you can see the versions used for fullcalendar and scheduler):
 `<ltng:require styles="{!join(',',
            $Resource.fullcalendar340 + '/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.css',
            $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.2/scheduler.css')}"
            scripts="{!join(',',
            $Resource.fullcalendar340 + '/fullcalendar-3.4.0/lib/jquery.min.js',
            $Resource.fullcalendar340 + '/fullcalendar-3.4.0/lib/moment.min.js',
            $Resource.fullcalendar340 + '/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.js',
            $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.2/scheduler.js')}"
            afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadScripts}"/>`